# got / had / have - are they interchangeable in this case?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

I didn't realize you **had** "ONE" in your name, Hermione!

I didn't realize you **have** "ONE" in your name, Hermione!

I didn't realize you **got** "ONE" in your name, Hermione!

Do these above sentences mean the same thing? Are they different from each other even slightly in meaning? (I'd love to learn the nuance.) If so, how are they different?

Answer (score 1):

The first is in clearly in the past; Hermione had "one" in her name and at some past time I hadn't realised it. The second talks about my non-realisation in the past but her name in the present. Either statement could be used if I had just realised that Hermione had "one" in her name.

"Got" means "acquired". It would only be correct (in AusE anyway) if Hermione was previously called (say) Matilda and had changed her name, and I hadn't realised that her name change gave a name with "one" in it.

Comment: Likewise in British English, but in informal speech we might say "you'd got" (you had got) or "you've got" (you have got) instead of "you had/have".

Comment: In American English, would it be correct to say "you got" in informal speech instead of "you had/have"?

Comment: Even in informal AmE, it would still be "you've got".